# doctrine how to merge incomplete data

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm creating an REST api with Symfony 4.2 and Doctrine as ORM connected to a MySQL database. I receive data in JSON , deserialize them with JMSSerializer and use the doctrine merge function to attach it. How can I merge the entity I got from the JSON with an already existing entity, updating only the given fields in the JSON?

Event entity

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;

/**
 * Event
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Event", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="Organiser", columns={"Organiser"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @Type("int")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Invited
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Invited",mappedBy="event",cascade={"persist","merge","remove"})
     * @Type("ArrayCollection<App\Entity\Invited>")
     */
    private $guests;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Type("string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="StartDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Type("DateTime")
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="EndDate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Type("DateTime")
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Place", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Type("string")
     */
    private $place;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ImagePath", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Type("string")
     */
    private $imagepath;

    /**
     * @var \User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Organiser", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     * @Type("App\Entity\User")
     */
    private $organiser;
?>
```

Deserialisation

```php
 $json = $request->getContent();
        $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $event = $serializer->deserialize($json,'App\Entity\Event','json');
```

Merging

```php
  $feedback = $this->em->merge($newEvent);
  $this->em->flush();
```

**Expected vs Actual results:**

If I have an already existing and attached event like:

```
{
 id:1,
 title: 'oldTitle',
 startDate: oldDate,
 place: 'oldPlace',
...
}
```

And I receive :

```
{
 id:1,
 title: 'newTitle'
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
 id:1,
 title: 'newTitle',
 startDate: oldDate,
 place: 'oldPlace',
...
}
```

Actual result when looking to the database:

```
{
 id:1,
 title: 'newTitle',
 startDate: null,
 place: null,
...
}
```

How can I achieve that in a efficient way?

Comment: the `merge` doesn't do, what you'd expect: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities you have to do the merge "manually" (i.e. not with doctrine), by first retrieving the object and probably giving it to the deserializer (perhaps?).

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer! I know that with the Default serializer, I can deserialize an object into another , but I didn't find the way to do it with JMS. Can it be done? Should I keep using JMS or should I switch back to the default serializer ?

Comment: as far as I can tell, the jms serializer can't deserialize into an existing object, but I only had a quick look. I'm not feeling comfortable giving advice though. *I* probably would use the symfony serializer and add validation that ensures the correct types. (however, when it comes  to relations ... you might have to write a custom deserializer anyway? dunno)